# Finding the polar decomposition of a $2\times2$ matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, matrix-decomposition, adjoint-operators

Specifically, the question is as follows:

> Let $B$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be such that
>   $$\mathcal{M}(T,B)=\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$$
>   Find the polar decomposition $T=S\sqrt{T^*T}$ of $T$. (Hint: The eigenvectors of $T^*T$ are $(1,2)$ and $(-2,1)$.)

It seems like this should be very straightforward. $T$ and $T^*$ are both invertible, so it should follow that $S=\sqrt{T(T^*)^{-1}}$, but this is false, as is easily checked (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(%7B%7B2,3%7D,%7B0,2%7D%7D%7B%7B2,0%7D,%7B3,2%7D%7D%5E-1)sqrt(%7B%7B2,0%7D,%7B3,2%7D%7D%7B%7B2,3%7D,%7B0,2%7D%7D)).

I'm not quite sure why the eigenvectors have been given considering the eigenvalues haven't been given, but the eigenvalues of $T^*T$ are $1$ and $16$. My other thought was to use the singular value decomposition to find the polar decomposition, but I run into similar computational issues. These attempts make me think I'm missing something theoretically. This is a homework question, so I request assistance in finding my error/hints to get to the true solution, but not an actual solution.

Comment: $T (\sqrt {T^* T})^{-1}$ seems not equal $\sqrt {T(T^*)^{-1}}$. This is not the arithmetic operation of real numbers. They are matrices, lots of things are different.

Comment: @xbh Sure, but $T=S\sqrt{T^*T}\Rightarrow T^2=S^2T^*T\Rightarrow T^2T^{-1}=S^2T^*\Rightarrow T=S^2T^*\Rightarrow T(T^*)^{-1}=S^2$, so in fact they should be equal, for invertible $T$ and $T^*$.

Comment: No, $(AB)^2 \neq A^2B^2$ generally,  and if $AB = BA$ the the equation holds. So the first $\implies$ is questionable.

Comment: Also $\sqrt T$ makes sense only when $T$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.

Comment: @xbh Ah, right! Rookie mistake.

Comment: @xbh Okay, so $\sqrt{T^*T}$ is invertible...why can't I solve for $S$ as $T(\sqrt{T^*T})^{-1}$?

Comment: This you can try, I think.

Comment: @xbh My apologies...it does work. It just required significant reducing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's a more elegant solution, but this works:

Observe that $T^*T=\begin{bmatrix}4&6\\6&16\end{bmatrix}$ and $\sqrt{T^*T}=\begin{bmatrix}2&\sqrt{6}\\\sqrt{6}&\sqrt{13}\end{bmatrix}$. Also, as is easily verified with a computational algebra engine, $$\sqrt{T^*T}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\sqrt{13}}{-6+2\sqrt{13}}&-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{-6+2\sqrt{13}}\\-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{-6+2\sqrt{13}}&\frac{2}{-6+2\sqrt{13}}\end{bmatrix}.$$
Similarly, 
$$S=T\sqrt{T^*T}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{3\sqrt{6}-2\sqrt{13}}{2(-3+\sqrt{13})}&-\frac{-3+\sqrt{6}}{-3+\sqrt{13}}\\
-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{-3+\sqrt{13}}&\frac{2}{-3+\sqrt{13}}\end{bmatrix}.$$
It is easily verified that this is the desired $S$.